# Why is my layout unable to be resolved? (Android/Java)

Tags: android, layout, resolve

Well, my program has been working so far, staying compilable and everything, and I tried to add a sound to it, so I created a folder "raw", and stuck in the mp3 file. Then I tried to use it, and everything started getting errors for whatever reason. I Ctrl+Z'd until it was back to before I tried adding sound. The program still error'd. I deleted the raw folder and there's still errors[marked in the program below] Note that this is only 1 class from my program, there are others.

```
package scouting.form;

import android.R;//Don't use android.R here; use a fully qualified name for each usage instead - this one only comes up *sometimes...*
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Login extends Activity {

    Button login;
    EditText user;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);//Error: activity_login cannot be resolved or is not a field
        login=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);//NO ERROR even though the next line has an error...
        user=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);//Error: editText1 cannot be resolved or is not a field
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent openScouting = new Intent("com.cody.graham.SCOUTING");
                startActivity(openScouting);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_login, menu);//Error: activity_login cannot be resolved or is not a field
        return true;
    }
}
```

I know that the layouts and menus are still there, they have been there the whole time, I can open the layouts and confirm that there is still an Edit Text box in the layout "activity_login" which is in the layout folder and the edit text box does have the line

```
android:id="@+id/editText1"
```

in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See at the top?

```
import android.R;//Don't use android.R here; use a fully qualified name for each usage instead - this one only comes up *sometimes...
```

You should probably heed what that comment says. ;) Remove the import for `android.R`, and it will use your project's `R` file instead, which is where `activity_login` is.

Comment: I don't know what to say... I did remove it at one point and it was complaining that I didn't have the import I needed so I re-added it. This time when I removed it, it worked... (facepalm?) Anyways, THANK YOU!!

Comment: @bluebl1 You're welcome! Don't forget to mark the answer as correct by ticking the checkmark on the left. ;)

Comment: I'm having the issue again that I was talking about. I have no "import.android.R" now, but I have this line:
'clr=(Button) findViewById(R.id.CLREntries);'
and it is saying that it can't resolve "CLREntries"
In the layout for this page, I have a button with this line:
'android:id="@+id/CLREntries"'
And there are no errors with the button.

Comment: Try cleaning the project. If that's not enough, post your full code and XML in a new question... as you just learned, swapping code in comments is.. well.. impossible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241769/why-does-this-r-glitch-happeneclipse-android-java

Answer (score 0):

You're importing the wrong `R.java`. You should be importing the one that is generated by Eclipse (in your *gen* folder). You can auto-import this by typing `control-shift-o`. You may also need to run Project>Clean, which is sometimes needed when adding assets.

As for the raw folder, be sure it is placed under the `res/` directory.